# Using CSS or HTML how can I eliminate the margins of a website?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am building the project section of my personal website.

It looks the following way:

[Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTRL0.jpg)

I am trying to get rid of the left margin so my image can start from the left margin.

This my current code:

```
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
  <div class="row-lg-4">
    <div class="hovereffect">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="../Projects/img/cyberSecurity.jpg" height = "600vh" width = "100vw" alt="">
            <div class="overlay">
                <h2>Effect 12</h2>
        <p>
          <a href="#">LINK HERE</a>
        </p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have tried doing inline CSS

```
<body style="margin:0; padding:0;">
```

It does not work.

I have also tried doing:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

}

in my css file. However, that did not work either.

Any sort of help would be highly appreciate it :D

Have a wonderful day.

Comment: Are you using IIS?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: @AndrewFan Yes I am using Bootstrap.

Comment: is the *{margin:0; padding:0; } at the very top of your css file? If not, move it to the top..

Comment: the bootstrap classes `col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4` are causing this. They add 15px of padding to the container. You need to wrap that element in a `row` element or target those with another class and remove the padding.

Answer (score 0):

To remove padding/margin in bootstrap, do something like this.

Add `no-padding` class to `padding: 0px;` for bootstrap columns and `no-marginLR` class to `margin-left:0;` and `margin-right:0;` for bootstrap rows.

here, `no-padding` and `no-marginLR` are used as example purpose.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row no-marginLR">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 no-padding">
      ...your code
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple columns that go edge to edge you could just use `.no-gutters` on the `.row` and make sure it's not nested in a `.container`.

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">.col-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-8</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4">.col-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some stuff that you should fix in order to get this done without any kind of "force".

You need to wrap the all this in one row div (div class="row"), since a column must be inside a row like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
         <div class="row-lg-4>
            <div class="hovereffect">
                 <img class="img-responsive" src="../Projects/img/cyberSecurity.jpg" height = "600vh" width = "100vw" alt="">
                 <div class="overlay">
                    <h2>Effect 12</h2>
                    <p>
                     <a href="#">LINK HERE</a>
                    </p>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Make sure that `" <div class="hovereffect">"` doesnt have any kind of spacing property added in the CSS File.

This line by default would have a padding of 15px, so you can get rid of this padding by adding the class "px-0". (if it is inside of a row, you dont need to do this).

```
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
```

As a final resource if any of these worked for you (they should work since thats how the grid system works), you can created your own not padding class that would look like this:

```
.nospacing {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Then you can add it to any of your HTML Tags.